# How do I undesignate mine wall?

Tags: gnomoria

I am probably just being dense, but I cannot find a way to undesignated "mine wall" marked blocks. If I accidentally mark a block to be mined and I change my mind before the gnomes start to mine it, how do I undesignated it? Nothing I've tried so far has worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the highest level menu there is a big X button as the last option. It is the "Cancel Job" Button. Use this to cancel any commands you make.

Comment: Installing the game on OSX from Steam, the main button list only goes to 8, there is nothing in slot 9 or 10. I had to bind a key to Cancel Job in the controls menu.